# What Protocol does Slither.io Use? Websocket? UDP?

Tags: http, web, real-time

I would like to develop a real time multi-game through a web browser.
Simple chat can be implemented simply via websocekt or ajax  but not real-time games. So I'm wondering how Slither.io games are made. Play with a web browser without installing it.What technique should I use? Do I have to use udp because it is real time? But does http webserver not support udp?Will it be real time enough to be a web socket?

Comment: real-time web games can use websockets, why are you saying they can't?

Comment: also udp is not allowed on the browser for security reasons, thus your only option is really tcp which is what websockets are a wrapper around

Comment: It seems slither.io is using WebSocket. You can open browser console and make a check.

Answer (score 1):

Websockets are more than fast enough for a game like Slither.io. I am more impressed with how their back-end is working.

Most people will tell you that Slither.io uses Node.js, Websockets, and HTML5 Canvas. While this is a great stack for a simple prototype game, I don't think Node.js is behind the performance Slither.io has. The main reasoning is that Node.js is single-threaded. (See my [answer here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-tech-stack-used-to-develop-slither-io/answer/Ryan-Pelletier-1) explaining this more)

A friend and I wrote a game to see what kind of technical challenges were present with a game like Slither.io. We used Node.js, Websockets, and HTML5 canvas. It is open source and currently on my GitHub. Feel free to play around with it to see how it works. [Here is my game](https://github.com/ryanp102694/tank-game)